# How to get the change the drop event target in Jquery UI Drag & Drop

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a grid(table) with each td as droppable. Also have a div which is a draggable. When I drag the div, the selected droppable is always the td in the middle. However I would want the td to the one which is under the start of the div. How to get this ?

[Use case JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by46ms9c/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
 <table border="1"></table>
 <div class="floater"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
  var size = [10, 10]
  for(var i = 0; i< size[0]; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>')
    for(var j = 0; j < size[1]; j++) {
      var td = $('<td></td>')
      tr.append(td)
    }
    $('.parent table').append(tr)
  }

  var dropFunc = function(event, ui) {
        $(event.target).addClass('dropped')
  }

  var overFunc = function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).addClass('over')
  }

  var outFunc = function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).removeClass('over')
  }
  $('td').droppable({over : overFunc, out : outFunc, drop : dropFunc})

  $('.floater').draggable()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to change the [droppable `tolerance` property](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) to `'pointer'` so that the `over` event is only fired when the cursor pointer overlaps the droppable element.

Then you can automatically set the position of the cursor on the draggable element to the top left by changing the [`cursorAt` property](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cursorAt).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3p8zngy/)

```
$('td').droppable({
  over: overFunc,
  out: outFunc,
  drop: dropFunc,
  tolerance: 'pointer'
});

$('.floater').draggable({
  cursorAt: {
    top: 5,
    left: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: Super thanks for the answer.. I had come up with a solution using a `handle` property to do the same. However, then the handle size becomes kinda critical and a dependency. Like ur answer better..